# TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given after installing Tensorflow 2.5 in venv at Windows 10

Tags: python, numpy, tensorflow, tensorflow2.0

currently I am following Tensorflow website (https://www.tensorflow.org/install/pip) to install latest Tensorflow 2.5 in my Windows 10 machine. I have installed python3.7, CUDA 11 and latest cudnn. Then I created the venv as mentioned in Tensorflow website and I use the command

```
pip install tensorflow
```

to install Tensorflow. However, after installed, when I tried to run the model.fit function, it triggered the error as follows:

```
File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\training.py", line 1147, in fit
    steps_per_execution=self._steps_per_execution)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1364, in get_data_handler
    return DataHandler(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 1166, in __init__
    model=model)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 939, in __init__
    **kwargs)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 809, in __init__
    peek, x = self._peek_and_restore(x)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\keras\engine\data_adapter.py", line 943, in _peek_and_restore
    return x[0], x
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 65, in __getitem__
    return self._get_batches_of_transformed_samples(index_array)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\iterator.py", line 231, in _get_batches_of_transformed_samples
    x = img_to_array(img, data_format=self.data_format)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\site-packages\keras_preprocessing\image\utils.py", line 309, in img_to_array
    x = np.asarray(img, dtype=dtype)
  File "C:\Users\xxx\xxx\lib\site-packages\numpy\core\_asarray.py", line 83, in asarray
    return array(a, dtype, copy=False, order=order)
TypeError: __array__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given
```

Basically the code I am running is working well at other machine but I not sure why it will trigger this error at this new machine. I have repeatedly to try, even use Anaconda with pip to install the Tensorflow, but same error still happened. I am sincerely appreciate if anyone can give me some guidance to solve this.

Thank you very much

Comment: Do you have different numpy versions on both systems?

Comment: Are you using a numpy library? and please tell me the version of PIL you are using: `import PIL`, then `print(PIL.__version__)`.

Comment: Hi, @Dr. Snoopy, thank you very much for your question. So far both system I am using same numpy version, which is 1.19.5 where it is automatically installed when installing the Tensorflow.

Comment: Hi @Kaveh, thank you very much for your question. My PIL version is 8.3.0

Comment: Check my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/68239032/2423278). It may be solved by downgrading pillow to 8.2.0.

Comment: HI @Kaveh, you are correct ~ after downgrading the pillow 8.2.0, it works now ~ You are very amazing ~ Thank you very much ~ appreciate a lot ~